# app crashes after segue call

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, segue

i have an application running on an iPad. in view (view1) one there are some objects the user can click. when an object is clicked i'll show another screen containg some detail information about the object on view 2.

view1 is embedded in a navigational controller and i've created a segue from view1 to view 2 called mySeq and of type push.

when the user click an object the following function is called:

```
- (void)easyTableView:(EasyTableView *)easyTableView selectedView:(UIView *)selectedView atIndex:(NSUInteger)index deselectedView:(UIView *)deselectedView {
[self borderIsSelected:YES forView:selectedView];       
if (deselectedView) 
    [self borderIsSelected:NO forView:deselectedView];

UILabel *label  = (UILabel *)selectedView;
bigLabel.text   = label.text;
    NSLog(@"Dette er en tekst");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySeg" sender:self];
}
```

view2 shows up with information and all. but when i click on the view - no matter where - the app crashes.

xcode tells me that it is in this line in my appdelegate:

```
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([EasyTableAppDelegate class]));
}
```

errorcode:
Program received signal: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

so obviously some kind of memory violation.

but what am i missing? do i need some extra setup or???

haven't got a clue.

thanks for any input.

kim

Comment: So view2 does show up but clicking crashes the app? Sounds like it's not a segue problem. Do make sure to check the application output, since a lot more information usually goes there than just `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: all i see is this:2011-12-03 23:31:46.762 Test123[16458:f803] Dette er en tekst
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: i wonder if i have to do something specific in view1 upon return from view2.